# cannot find symbol Queue Java

Tags: java

I cannot compile below and keep getting an error like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx9Aw.png)

I have done the code on visual studio code and the file name is like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkjN0.png)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
            q.add(i);
        
        System.out.println("Elements of queue " + q);

        int removedele = q.remove();
        System.out.println("removed element-" + removedele);
        System.out.println(q);

        int head = q.peek();
        System.out.println("head of queue-" + head);
        System.out.println(q);

        int size = q.size();
        System.out.println("Size of queue-" + size);
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

[I copied the code from my lecturers video and in her vid, the code compiles fine. But the source code is of extension .main. I cant seem to do that here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw2n6.png)

Comment: Im very new to java and its hard learning online

Comment: Either rename the file to Main.java or change the class name to `call`.

Comment: And add the correct imports. For example: `import java.util.*`.

Comment: @Unmitigated I did rename to Main.java and it fixed 1/3 of the errors. It still has the other 2 errors

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw2n6.png This is where I got the code from, it is of extension .main but when I do .main, file doesnt open in vsc

Comment: The file extension isn't `.main`. The *package* ends in `main`.

Comment: It seems like you have two issues going on here. First, you need to name your file Main.java to have a class named Main and you are missing imports for LinkedList.

Comment: @erasvv Like I said before, you need to add the correct imports. For example: `import java.util.*;`

Answer (score 0):

add following at line at the top.
`import java.util.*;`

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the import statements for Queue and LinkedList. Java needs to know what Classes you are referring to and where they can be found.

Add this to the top of the file:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
```